# Simplest way to ensure var is vector

Tags: clojure

What is the "simplest"/shortest way to ensure a var is a vector? Self-written it could look like

```
(defn ensure-vector [x]
  (if (vector? x)
    x
    (vector x))

(ensure-vector {:foo "bar"})
;=> [{:foo "bar"}]
```

But I wonder if there is already a core function that does this? Many of them (`seq`, `vec`, `vector`, `list`) either fail on maps or always apply.

I also wonder what would be the best name for this function. `box`, `singleton`, `unit`, `v`, `cast-vector`, `to-vector`, `->vector`, `!vector`, `vector!`, `vec!`?

I further wonder if other languages, like Haskell, have this function built-in.

Comment: Haskell doesn't have this function built in, because it is impossible to write in Haskell. What would its type be?

Comment: @amalloy: It is not impossible in haskell, check `Data.Dynamic`. The correct statement would be usually you don't do such things in haskell.

Comment: You could say it's possible, but I don't think that's the normal interpretation, nor a very useful one. My point is that there can exist no function `f` in haskell such that `(f 1) == [1]` and `(f [1] == [1])`, because it can't be typed. You can write `g :: Dynamic -> Dynamic`, but it's a pain to work with and not very safe (and, of course, doesn't fill in for `f` in this example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the function you want to use when the value is a collection is [`vec`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/vec) which turns any collection into a vector. The [`vector`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/vector) function receives the items of the resulting vector as its arguments, so you could use it when the value is neither a vector or a collection.

This is a possible approach:

```
(defn as-vector [x]
  (cond
    (vector? x) x
    (sequential? x) (vec x)
    :else (vector x)))

(map as-vector [[1] #{2 3} 1 {:a 1}])
```

I chose the name for the function based on the ones from the `Coercions` protocol in `clojure.java.io` (`as-file` and `as-url`).

Comment: `coll?` includes maps which makes `(vec {})` into `[[]]` violating my constraint. But changing `coll?` into `sequential?` would work.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought you wanted vectors with map values too, but I just changed it to match your constraint.