# Clojure: built-in or one-line solution to insert nil into a collection

Tags: collections, clojure

Consider the following function call: `(into [] (some_expression))`

Let's say that `(some_expression)` may either yield `nil`, or some valid vector (e.g. `[1 2 3]`). What I would like to achieve is, that if the result of `(some_expression)` is `nil`, then I end up with `[nil]`, instead of `[]` (after executing `into`). (Of course, if it is some valid vector, like `[1 2 3]`, then I would like to have `[1 2 3]`.)

Possibilities I've considered so far:

- [`vec`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/vec): wrong, because `(vec nil) = []`, thus the end result is still `[]`
- [`vector`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/vector): wrong, since `(vector [1 2 3]) = [[1 2 3]]`, thus, the end result will be `[[1 2 3]]`. (It would work for `nil`, though.)
- custom function, like `ensure-vector` or `as-vector` in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710570/simplest-way-to-ensure-var-is-vector): that would solve the problem, but I'm asking if there is something shorter (maybe built into Clojure) that achieves the same
- I'm also aware of the following work-around, but it is a bit clumsy for me: `(into [] (let [result (some_expression)] (if (nil? result) [nil] result)))`

I'm afraid there is no short solution, because otherwise it would have been mentioned in that question; still that one is quite old, so I'm hoping maybe they added that feature to Clojure since then.

Also, there are some key differences with that question:

- As stated above, the "`ensure-vector`" I'm looking for has to work only for `nil`. (I.e., it is fine if `(ensure-vector 2)` returns `2` and not `[2]`.) I guess this does not really count, but who knows.
- An approach, which is completely different than "`ensure-vector`" would be fine too. E.g., if `into` had some special parameter that caused it to interpret the `from` argument as a value to be inserted, instead of the source collection, that would also solve my problem. (This is more for the sake of making an example: as far as I understand the [documentation of into](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/into), it does not have such form. Although, frankly, I'm not quite sure what `xform` means in `(into to xform from)`. But I guess it is something else...)

Comment: Short and not-very-thougtful: have you considered a filter or conditional lambda type wrapper?

Comment: Does `(into [] (or (some-expression) [nil]))` meet your needs?

Comment: @FrankC.: I don't know what you mean, sorry (I guess you refer to `filter` function, but I don't understand how it would help in this case)

Comment: As I said, my comment was not too thoughtful. @Nick has provided an optimal solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[or](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/or) allows you to specify a fallback of `[nil]` if `some-expression` yields `nil` or `false`:

`(into [] (or (some-expression) [nil]))`

- https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/or